# .load html code without replacing div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I use

```
$('#new-nav1').load("/yiite/index.php/includes/load_second #table",{

      ID:ID,name:name,ord:ord
});
```

I want to put it under loaded data, there will be a lot of data, that`s why load it into another div is not the solution
Every time it replaces elements in idv #new-nav1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append after the data is loaded using a temporary div.

```
$("<div/>").load("/yiite/index.php/includes/load_second #table", {
    ID: ID, name: name, ord: ord
}, function () {
    $(this).appendTo("#loaded-data").unwrap();//unwrap removes the temp div
});
```

Comment: did you replace "#loaded-data" with your id?

Comment: yes, of course may be div at the beginning must be closed

Comment: I found , i just swapped unwrap()-secondly and appendTo()-firstly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to ajax call as shown below..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "/yiite/index.php/includes/load_second #table",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {ID:ID,name:name,ord:ord},
        success: function(responseText){
            $('#new-nav1').append(responseText);
        },
        error: function(responseText){
        }
    });
    });
```

For more information :-

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/